# Discount Coupon System for php

Tags: javascript, php, cart, coupon

can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code?

I'm trying to apply a coupon from mysql database. But this simple php variable is not being executed.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Coupon test code</title> 
<style>
#error{
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head> 

<body> 
    <form name="couponField" action=""> 
        <span id="error"></span>
        Coupon code: 
        <input type="coupon" id="coupon" name="coupon"> 
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Apply Coupon Code"> 
    </form> 
<?php $promo = "total"; ?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#submit').click(function(){
  var input = $('#coupon').val();
  var promo = <?php echo $promo; ?>;
  if(input === promo){
    $('#error').text('correct code!');
  } else if (input !== ''){
    $('#error').text('wrong code!');
  }
});
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need quotes where you assign the value to your `promo` variable. At least, when I view source in the browser, there are none, which seems strange, and it throws an error which shows on the developer console with an undefined variable. It even tells you line the error is on.

Comment: that is the main problem... php vaiable is not working with js

Comment: As said, you have to put quotes to asign the value use :  `var promo = <?php echo "{$promo}"; ?>;`. It's clearly explained on this link :
https://www.dummies.com/programming/php/how-to-display-php-variable-values/

Comment: @JulienMaret doesn't work....

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line inside your javascript function:

```
var promo = <?php echo $promo; ?>;
```

This is fixed by enclosing the php tags with quotes:

```
var promo = '<?php echo $promo; ?>';
```

This issue is due to the fact that PHP doesn't understand that the variable you are echoing is going to be passed as an string value to another variable in javascript; so while running the code javascript sees:

```
var promo = total;
```

instead of:

```
var promo = 'total';
```

Comment: Thanks... It now works fine... if u please give me a little suggestion for validating coupon from database!!!

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Validation process usually defers depending on the goal and required security level for the project. For a coupon I would recommend storing all the coupons in a SQL table and each time a coupon code is entered, it should be searched to see whether it is inside the coupons table (and so valid) or not (invalid). You can also count the number of times a coupon is used and set a column 'active' (which should be 1 by default) to 0 after a specific number of times it has been used.